# Online noise removal techniques

Tags: dataset, data-mining, data-cleaning, kalman-filter

There are lots of noise removal algorithms for offline dataset. I would like to ask if there are some suitable online implementations to remove noise of the data in real-time (similar to Kalman Filtering- though I could not come up with suitable parameters to successfully use it.)